# Routing with Django and React

Tags: python, django, reactjs, react-router

I'm very new to working with Django and I've been relying on some tutorials to link this one to React, but the problem is that initially (when I open 127.0.0.1:8000) React loads the routes perfectly, then when I reload the page Django tries to interpret the path from `urls.py` and obviously can't find it.

The error is:

```
Page not found (404) Using the URLconf defined in memberstack.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
api/token-auth/
core/
```

I hope you can help me, thanks in advance

**my_project/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework_jwt.views import obtain_jwt_token
from frontend.views import index

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('frontend.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/token-auth/', obtain_jwt_token),
    path('core/', include('core.urls')),
]
```

**frontend/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
]
```

**frontend/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'frontend/index.html')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, you'll have to use a catch-all in order for React to handle all the routing instead of django there.

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('frontend.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/token-auth/', obtain_jwt_token),
    path('core/', include('core.urls')),
    re_path(r'^(?:.*)/?$', include('frontend.urls')),
]
```

Or

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    re_path(r'^(?:.*)/?$', views.index)
]
```

I think the better practice would be to implement Django-Rest-Framework and build them separately.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm thinking, I'm noticing the code is getting a little complex to handle. I'll take the advice to do it separately, anyway thank you very much (your advice worked)

Comment: Glad to hear it, you're very welcome. Setting up your backend with API support will just be less of a headache in the future if you want to change your frontend at some point!